# Min&Max Heap implementation in .NET

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, heap, heap-sort

### **Overview**

I was doing some performance optimization patterns when I stumbled upon `PriorityQueue` and I implemented for that reason `Heap` data structure, but I wanted you guys to tell me if I did something wrong. I am trying to achieve max performance and slight abstraction over the structure (what I mean by that is I gave the opportunity to the caller to decide if he creates max or min heap).

### Code

`IHeap.cs`

```
namespace DataStructures.Heap
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    /// <summary>
    ///   Represents heap data structure.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the parameters stored in the heap.</typeparam>
    public interface IHeap<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Builds heap out of array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="array">Array to build heap from.</param>
        void Build(T[] array);

        /// <summary>
        ///  Adds element to the heap.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="element">Element to add.</param>
        void Add(T element);

        /// <summary>
        ///  Extracts element from the heap.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns> Extracted element.</returns>
        T Extract();
    }
}
```

`HeapType.cs`

```
namespace DataStructures.Heap
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  Used to describe what type a heap will be.
    /// </summary>
    public enum HeapType
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Max heap is a heap with largest element on top of each tree and sub-tree
        ///  when array is represented as a binary tree.
        /// </summary>
        Max,
        /// <summary>
        ///  Min heap is heap with smallest element on top of each tree and sub-tree
        ///  when array is represented as a binary tree.
        /// </summary>
        Min
    }
}
```

`Heap.cs`

```
namespace DataStructures.Heap
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    /// <summary>
    ///  Represents max heap data struture.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the elements in the heap.</typeparam>
    public class Heap<T> : IHeap<T>
    {
        private T[] _heap;
        private readonly HeapType _heapType;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Used to validate property of the heap. Either smallest 
        ///  element should be always root of each tree and sub-tree in a context of min heap
        ///  or largest when dealing with max heap.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly Func<int, int, T[], bool> _heapPropertyValidator;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Heap{T}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="heap"> Array of type <typeparamref name="T"/></param>
        /// <param name="heapType"> Determines what kind of heap this instance will be. It can be any tye of <see cref="HeapType"/>.</param>
        public Heap(T[] heap, HeapType heapType)
        {
            _heap = heap;
            _heapType = heapType; 
            Count = heap.Length;

            switch (heapType)
            {
                case HeapType.Max:
                    _heapPropertyValidator =
                        (comparingIndex, comparingIndex2, array) =>
                            comparingIndex < Count && Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(array[comparingIndex], array[comparingIndex2]) > 0;
                    break;
                case HeapType.Min:
                    _heapPropertyValidator =
                        (comparingIndex, comparingIndex2, array) =>
                            comparingIndex < Count && Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(array[comparingIndex], array[comparingIndex2]) < 0;
                    break;
#if DEBUG
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(heapType), heapType, null);
#endif
            }

            Build(_heap);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Gets total number of elements in the heap.
        /// </summary>
        public int Count { get; private set; }
        public T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
#if DEBUG
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(index));
                }
#endif
                return _heap[index];
            }
            set
            {
#if DEBUG
                if (value == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
                }
#endif
                _heap[index] = value;
            }
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        /// <remarks> Takes O(nlogn) time complexity. </remarks>
        public void Add(T element)
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (element == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(element));
            }
#endif
            _heap[Count] = element;
            Count++;

            Heapify(_heap, Count);
        }

        /// <remarks>
        ///  Maintains the heap property with the help of <see cref="_heapPropertyValidator"/> function.
        ///  Takes O(nlogn) time complexity. 
        /// </remarks>
        private void Heapify(T[] array, int index = 0)
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (array == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
            }
#endif
            while (true)
            {
                var left = Left(index);
                var right = Right(index);
                var toSwap = index;

                if(_heapPropertyValidator.Invoke(left, index, array))
                {
                    toSwap = left;
                }
                if(_heapPropertyValidator.Invoke(right, toSwap, array))
                {
                    toSwap = right;
                }
                if (toSwap != index)
                {
                    array.Swap(index, toSwap);
                    index = toSwap;
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        ///<inheritdoc />
        /// <remarks> Takes O(n) time complexity. </remarks>
        public void Build(T[] array)
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (array == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
            }
#endif
            for (var i = Count / 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Heapify(array, i);
            }
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        /// <remarks> 
        ///  This method extracts top element of the heap. 
        ///  For max heap this is max element for min heap this is min element.
        ///  Time complexity of this method is O(logn).
        /// </remarks>
        public T Extract()
        {
            // first element is always max element.
            var result = _heap[0];

            // swap last element with first one and reduce the count, as we will
            // remove last element afterwards.
            _heap[0] = _heap[--Count];
            _heap = _heap.RemoveAt(Count);

            // heapify the heap as we broke the property.
            Heapify(_heap);
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Sorts the heap without modifying it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks> 
        ///  This method will sort the heap in asc(when the heap is of type min) and 
        ///  desc(when the heap is of type max). This has O(nlogn) time complexity.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns> Sorted enumerable in descending order.</returns>
        public IEnumerable<T> Sort()
        {
            // TODO: Check if move semantics are available in C#
            var heap = new Heap<T>(_heap, _heapType);
            var result = new T[Count];
            for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = heap.Extract();
            }
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Gets the parent index of the <paramref name="index"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index">Index to which parent index will be searched for.</param>
        /// <returns> Parent index. </returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private static int Parent(int index)
            => (index & 1) == 0 ? (index >>= 1) - 1 : (index >>= 1);

        /// <summary>
        ///  Gets the index of left child of given index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index">Index to found left child index to.</param>
        /// <returns> Index of the left child of the element with given index.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private static int Left(int index)
            => (index <<= 1) + 1;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Gets the index of right child of given index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index">Index to found right child index to.</param>
        /// <returns> Index of the right child of the element with given index.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private static int Right(int index)
            => (index <<= 1) + 2;

        #region IEnumerable
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<T>)_heap).GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
        #endregion
    }
}
```

`Extensions.cs`

```
using System;

namespace DataStructures
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Swaps two elements at two given indexes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the elements in the array.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="array"> The array which will swap values from.</param>
        /// <param name="firstIndex"> Index that will be swaped with index number two.</param>
        /// <param name="secondIndex"> Index that will be swaped with index number one.</param>
        /// <throws><see cref="ArgumentException"/></throws>
        public static void Swap<T>(this T[] array, int firstIndex, int secondIndex)
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (array == null)
            {
               throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
            }
            if (firstIndex > array.Length || firstIndex < 0 ||
                secondIndex > array.Length || secondIndex < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("One of the indexes is out of range.");
            }
#endif
            var temp = array[firstIndex];
            array[firstIndex] = array[secondIndex];
            array[secondIndex] = temp;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Removes element from array at index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the elements in the array.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="array"> Array to remove item from.</param>
        /// <param name="index"> Index which will be removed.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns new array without the element at passed index.</returns>
        public static T[] RemoveAt<T>(this T[] array, int index)
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (array == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
            }
            if (index < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(index));
            }
#endif
            var dest = new T[array.Length - 1];
            if (index > 0)
                Array.Copy(array, 0, dest, 0, index);

            if (index < array.Length - 1)
                Array.Copy(array, index + 1, dest, index, array.Length - index - 1);

            return dest;
        }
    }
}
```

Should I continue abstract the class by providing a way of passing `heapPropertyValidator` function or this should be concerns to the user of the heap?

Comment: Are `T[].RemoveAt` and `T[].Swap` extention methods? Please provide all the code necessary to compile and run this!

Comment: Right, I forgot, check my edited answer I added them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snowbody has already covered some of my pre-OP-edit answer... though I will disagree that `HeapType` has too many comments: inline documentation is great and should be as comprehensive as possible. There is a bit of overlap between our answers, but I think I've filtered out anything which doesn't add anything.

## General Comments

Nice simple interface, though I'd personally appreciate properties for `Count`, `Empty`, and maybe a `Peek()` method. It is currently impossible to determine whether calling `IHeap<T>.Extract()` makes any sense, and it isn't clear what will happen if you do call `Extract()` on an empty Heap (I'll come back to that later...).

This comment on the `Heap<T>` class is misleading:

> Represents max heap data struture.

## Array and `Build`

Why is `_heap` an array?!?! The whole `Build` thing is a bit weird, but I can live with that. What I *can't* live with, is the fact that you are using a fixed-size array, not doing any upper-bounds checking on it, and not declaring that the `Heap` is limited by the size of the array it is built with! Don't use an array! Use a `List<T>`!!

`Heap.ctor(T[], HeapType)` modifies the provided array, *and* uses it for internal representation! This is a disaster of epic proportions! You've ruined the user's data, and now they can return the favour by corrupting your heap! Even more fun, because `RemoveAt<T>(int)` creates a *new* array (which is an \$O(n)\$ operation, and exactly something that Heaps are meant to avoid) this behaviour will change when `Add` is called. You should be using a `List<T>`, not an array, and you should be creating it yourself, not accepting it from in a constructor.

If you really want a fixed-size heap (as I think Snowbody is assuming, but if this is the case it should be clearly documented), then you just need to change `RemoveAt(int)` to default out the last element, rather than produce a new array.

The greatest sin, however, is that `Build()` - a *public* facing *insance* method - modifies the array it is passed and *doesn't* fill the Heap. This is exactly the opposite of the behaviour I would expect!

## Member by Member stuff

### `_heapPropertyValidator`

This feels really clunky. Why are you passing an array and two indicies, when you could just pass the two elements to be *compared*? Why is it a "Property Validator", when it could just be a comparer? Your 2 implementations in the constructor both perform a check on one of the elements, which should really be done by `Heapify(T[], int)` before calling it. It is completely unclear why this check is done.

I would use the existing [Comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate (or `IComparer`, as Snowbody says), and consider renaming it. This would allow you to provide a constructor which takes a custom comparator (because it wouldn't have any uncessary duties), but this wouldn't tally with it being either a `min` or `max` heap (unless you wrapped one explicitly and negated the comparison result, or modified `Heapify`).

You asked if this would be a good abstraction: given you don't need to remember the `HeapType`, I would say it would be valuable, not least because `DefaultComparator` is slow. However, you'd have to consider the API carefully, because currently it tries to be 'agnostic': if you accepted a comparator, you'd have to delare it as either a min or max heap in the appropriate constructors.

### `Heap.ctor(T[], HeapType)`

```
#if DEBUG
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(heapType), heapType, null);
#endif
```

This is a valuable check: it shouldn't be restricted to debug mode.

You ought perhaps to be caching the result of `Comparer<T>.Default`: currently your lambdas have to look it up each time, and I can't remember if it does its own caching.

### `this[int]`

I don't know why you have provided a public indexer: as far as I'm aware, no one has ever wanted to index into a Heap, it isn't terribly meaningful. You are sensibly checking whether the index is too small, but as Snowbody says, you also ought to be checking if it is too big (greater than or equal to `Count`), and you are only performing this check on the `getter`. As snowbody also says, the `setter` absolutely should *not* be public, because it can break the Heap. I would remove this indexer completely.

Personal choice, but I prefer the overloads of `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert` over `#if DEBUG` blocks. It isn't entirely clear why you would only want to run these checks under the debugger. A public method should be difficult (if it can't be impossible) to misuse without shouting at the consumer.

### `Add(T element)`

Is there any particular reason why you disallow `null` values? This constraint should be documented.

You are assigning into an array at an index which may be greater than the array:

_heap[Count] = element;

As said before, `_heap` should be a dynamic structure controlled by the Heap: it should be perfectly fine to call `Add` on any Heap any time: the only allowable crash would be from tacitly ignored concurrancy concerns, or from lack of resources (Stack-overflow/Out-of-memory).

I havn't implemented a `Heap` myself for a while, but as Snowbody agrees, this looks very wrong:

```
Heapify(_heap, Count);
```

I think that `Count` shold be a `0`. `Count` isn't even a valid index into `_heap` at this point. Quite simply, `Add` doesn't work; try this piece of code:

```
Heap<int> heap = new Heap<int>(new int[] { 5, 2, 6, 4, 1, 3 }, HeapType.Min);
Console.WriteLine(heap.Extract());
heap.Add(0);
Console.WriteLine(heap.Extract());
```

I took the liberty of re-writing `RemoveAt` so that it is constant-time, and doesn't reduce the size of the array, because otherwise this code would crash.

It *should* print `1` and then `0`, but it prints `1` and then `2`.

> Takes O(nlogn) time complexity.

Should be `O(log(n))`.

### `Heapify`

This is another confusing method which performs general operations on arrays, not on the data-structure.

> Takes O(nlogn) time complexity.

Is hopefully a lie, it should be `O(log(n))`.

### `Build(T[])`

Again, been a while since I had to understand Binary Heaps, so I couldn't say if this is right or not (cursory testing suggests it works), <s>but it is not `O(n)`, this is `O(n*log(n))`</s> it *is* `O(n)`, my memory of algorithms betrays me again.

If this is to be a public facing method, then the `null` check should be kept for release builds.

### `Extract()`

This method will crash if called on an Empty heap and throw an exception, which is good, but it will be a really unhelpful exception. You should be checking whether the Heap is empty, and throwing an `IllegalOperation` exception or similar with a meaningful message ("Can't extract an element from an empty heap").

You really need an `IsEmpty` or `Count` property on the interface, and perhaps a `bool TryExtract(out T result)` method so the Heap can be safely consumed.

`RemoveAt` is a problem. It makes this operation `O(n)`, not `O(log(n))`, as it should be. It also replaces the array, which further confounds the whole escaped-state business. Use a `List<T>`, where calling `RemoveAt(int)` on the last element will be constant time (no copy).

### `Sort()`

Without reading the comments, this looks like an in-place sort, which doesn't make much sense, but then nor does the comment, which suggests "this method will sort the heap". Consider rephrasing that to something along the lines of "this method will return every element in the Heap sorted...". I'd also consider renaming the method, to something like "EnumerateSorted()", but this is just taste.

You are missing an opportunity here to use `yield` to stream the sorted elements, which means if the consumer only needs half the elements, they can avoid poping the other half. This is kind of the behaviour I would expect from a Heap, otherwise there is no alogrithmic benefit to using a Heap rather than just enumerating the collection and using Quick/Merge/Genericnlogn Sort.

If you do wish to return a flat data-structure instead, then consider actually returning an array. I can't think of any real reason not to.

Time complexity looks correct on this one ;)

### `Parent(int)`

I'm not sure what this is meant for... but it looks wrong, and it is never used, so remove it.

## Key Points

- Do as Snowbody says, and encapsulate your *own* representation: don't expose this to anyone.
- Make that representation a `List<T>`, and call `List<T>.Add(T)` to add to it, and `List<T>.RemoveAt(int)` to remove from it.
- Add a `Count` member to the `IHeap<T>` interface
- Fix `Add`
- More comprehensive argument checks, and leave them in the release build
- TEST THE CODE

Comment: For the downvoter who said there are bugs which can be discovered easily IF I tested -> https://github.com/kuskmen/DesignPatterns/blob/master/DesignPatterns/Tests/HeapTests.cs Not saying like these are proper tests -> obviously I missed something, but in the end I am just exercising its not matter of life and death thankfully. Anyway, thanks a lot for the review I will definitely make all the changes you and @Snowbody described and take the most of them.

Comment: About the Build complexity I think you are both wrong, O(nlogn) is simple analysis check this lecture -> https://youtu.be/B7hVxCmfPtM?t=34m39s
 One more thing tho, could you elaborate more on why to use `List` instead of `array` after all `List` uses internally array? Yes, I need to polish the way I am using it, but I don't see a point using List instead of array if I do everything properly with the array operations? Perhaps I am wrong tho?

This Comparison delegate... thanks a lot for the suggestion this is amazing, didn't know about it!

Comment: @kuskmen note that you never test `Add`: I'm pretty sure that method can _only_ crash at the moment. I guess you're right about the build complexity (I'll have to go through that maths myself... eurgh, discrete maths...). `List<T>` over `T[]`, because it is much easier and clearer. You could manage the array yourself (i.e. implement `List<T>`), but `List<T>` will be pretty much as efficient, and will be _much_ easier to implement and maintain.

Comment: Yes, I obviously messed with the testing but tbh havent paid much attention to it as I should :) Anyway, thanks again for the review :)

Answer (score 3):

## `IHeap.cs`

- Why are you inheriting from `IEnumerable<T>` ? I don't see any reason why your heap would need to support the `IEnumerable` methods.
- One typo: you put "parameter" instead of "element"
- might want to clarify that `Extract()` takes the highest-priority element off the heap.
- The interface is more for a priority queue than a heap. A heap is one way of implementing a priority queue. It also could be implemented by an ordered list, an unordered list, or a standard binary tree. I suggest changing the name to `IPriorityQueue<T>`.

## `HeapType.cs`

- It's fine... probably has too many comments.
- I fully encourage you to allow the user to pass their own `heapPropertyValidator` delegate to the constructor. The type should be  `Func<T,T,bool>`. [Or maybe even `IComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The goal is to allow any item to be compared, even those that don't support `>`. (If you stick with this implementation of the class, you should probably [make sure that T implements `IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

## `Heap.cs`

- It's a bad idea to expose the implementation of the class to users of the class. It's bad form to have the caller have to provide the storage! Your class should provide the storage. What if the caller change the array between calls to your code? Your code could produce wrong results. The class methods should be the only means of manipulating its state. The parameter should be the max heap size.
- `public T this[int index]` should throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` if the index is less than 0 or more than the current heap size.
- Why in the world are you allowing callers to modify arbitrary elements of the heap? That could break the heap property!
- `public void Add(T element)` should check if the heap is full, throwing an exception if it is. Also I'm pretty sure it's log n complexity, not n log n. (It can only bubble up through log n levels)
- Why does `Heapify()` take the array as a parameter? It's already a member variable/field!
- I believe `Add()` calls `Heapify()` with the wrong value for `index`, leading to bad results if (say) there are negative numbers. This is a bug. The spurious 0 elements might get brought up into the heap, while the negative numbers get lost. (It should use `count/2` as does `Build()`.)
- What's the possible benefit of the default argument `index=0` on `Heapify()`?
- In `Parent()`, `Left()`, and `Right()`, you don't need to include the `=` sign in the shift operators; you're not needing to modify the value.